# Writing to HTML with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="edvTextGame.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="placeholder.css">
    </head>
    <div class="firstScreen">
        <div class="Title Fade">Placeholder</div>
        <button class="Fade" onclick="setTimeout(Start)"> Start </button>
    </div>
    <div class="introStoryScreen">
        <div class="JSGameText">
            <p id="intro" ></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

The used HTML

```
window.onerror = function(msg, url, linenumber) {
    alert('Error message: '+msg+'\nURL: '+url+'\nLine Number: '+linenumber);
    return true;
}

//FUNCTIONS

//  Intro sequence
function Start() {
    document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML = test;
}

//  Creator. -> Origin asign, name asign, stat asign
function CharCreation() {

}
```

The used JavaScript

The problem in these files is that the `document.getElementById` part is not functioning, it gives me an empty error.

My notepad++ also doesn't recognize/autofill when I type `.innerHTML` behind the `document.getElementById` part.

According to examples i've seen, this should work. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Remove `window.onerror` handler so that you can conveniently see a error in browser console. Then, try to execute it and write what you've got in your console.

Comment: What does 'empty error' mean? When do you call your Start function? It is possible that the DOM is not ready at that time.

Answer (score 1):

The error message will probably be about the assignment... what does 'test' reference to?
Maybe you meant:

```
document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML = "test";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `body.onload` function to ensure that the document was loaded and ready, then set the value. Note that by default, Javasciprt expects enclosed strings, or variables on operations.

```
function aFunction(){
   var aString = "test"
   document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML = aString;
}

<body onload="aFunction()">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the quotes in *test* :

`function Start() {
    document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML = "test";
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, in the HTML I was trying to add what I wanted to add to a P tag, I got rid of the P tag and made it write to the DIV tag instead, it works now.